# unserialize : Error at offset when getting field from database

Tags: php, serialization

I'm having an issue with this piece of code

```
unserialize($this->getConfigData('multi_payment_options'));
```

This line

```
$this->getConfigData('multi_payment_options')
```

returns this string from the database field that contains

```
{'_1615302093561_561':{'label':'Nul','minimum':'','maximum':'','contract':'',
'count':'1','period':'1','first':''}}
```

but doing this I'm getting the following error :

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 114 bytes
```

So doing some digging I understand there is an encodage issue with that string, but I don't know what it is not how to fix it. The field is supposed to store an array

Any ideas ?

Comment: That is JSON - serialized data is more like `a:3:{i:1;s:6:"elem 1";i:2...`

Comment: It's funny when you know it's a core functionnality, so basicaly that means they are using unserialize instead of json_decode there. It's from the Lyranetwork Payzen core.

Comment: It's not JSON either. JSON uses double quotes.